# Encounter error while submitting my app to App Store . How could i fixed it?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I have googled a lot but unable to resolve the error[image]

could any body tell me about this?

Comment: Check it in project directory.

Comment: its in the project directory and Bundle versions string, short
and
Bundle version are also there

Comment: Can you open your xarchive file and check if there is an Info.plist file in the root directory and in the Product>Applications><yourapp.app> directory?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the Info.plist in your project, whether it is in project or not, if plist is in your project then check your plist contain

> Bundle versions string, short

and

> Bundle version

in it, if any of them is not present then add this in your plist.

If it is also not a problem then go to your app target and select `Build Setting` and search for the plist file, check the path of the plist file is proper there.

Comment: Its in the project directory and Bundle versions string, short
and
Bundle version are also there

Comment: Have you checked build setting

Comment: Yes in build setting under the packaging Info.plistFile , address is written there where it is located

Comment: I am also confused why this is occuring